# compute a million distinct permutations of a given collection of numbers with Collections.shuffle()?

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I am currently undertaking an exercise on Project Euler, the tasks requires me to find the millionth permutation of a series of numbers, now I have two options either define my own algorithm to find the millionth permutation or use the `Collections.suffle()` method, however, I am not sure whether it's possible for the `Collections.suffle()` method to compute 1 million distinct permutations.

The millionth number is decided by sorting all the permutations, but you can ignore this part.

**My question:**

is it possible to generate 1 million distinct permutations of a series of numbers with `Collections.shuffle()` ? if not what do you think is the best approach or the most optimal approach to generate 1 million distinct permutations of a series of numbers?

this is the content provided from Project Euler:

> What is the millionth lexicographic permutation of the digits:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9?
```

please note - I don't actually want someone to solve the exercise for me. Just answering my question(s) above will do. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the question down voted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  Despite the fact that you say you don't want us to write code, there is no way to answer this question without doing so.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

collections.shuffle() just shuffle your array in a random permutation order. Since you need to follow the lexicographic order, you cannot use collections.shuffle(). And also when using collections.shuffle() the number of permutation times, it is not guaranteed that you will have all the permutation because collections.shuffle() can generate the same permutation many times. 
For how you can do, here is some good link that explain how to do it using factorial number system. [Find the N-th permutation of an ordered string (Using factorial number system).](https://ashprakasanblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/16/find-lexicographically-nth-permutation-of-an-ordered-string/)

Comment: as for the lexicographic order that would simply be Collections.sort() after the permutations have been generated. Yes, you're right that there will be a lot of duplicated permutations, however, I was hoping to use some sort of loop but only add the generated permutation if it isn't already contained within my permutations list and simply ignore the dupes. Thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look at the appended link.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
public static <V> HashSet<HashSet<V>> getCombos(HashSet<V> elements, int size) {
    HashSet<HashSet<V>> combos = new HashSet<HashSet<V>>();
    HashSet<V> inner = new HashSet<V>();
    recur(elements, combos, inner, size);
    return combos;

}

public static <V> HashSet<V> dupe(HashSet<V> orig) {
    return new HashSet<V>(orig);
}

public static <V> void recur(HashSet<V> curr, HashSet<HashSet<V>> combos, HashSet<V> base, int size) {
    if (curr.size() == size) {
        combos.add(dupe(curr));
    } else {
        HashSet<V> inner = dupe(base);
        for (V v : base) {
            inner.remove(v);
            curr.add(v);
            recur(curr, combos, inner, size);
            curr.remove(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Uses recursion to generate all unique combinations of size n given a set of elements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.